# Napili Community - Branding Tokens for Default Login Page

Tags: community, customer-community, community-builder

I have been able to use Branding Tokens in Lightning Components within the main Napili community, with a degree of success. with reference to the image and code below:

[image]

[Link to resource I used for tokens](https://blogs.comitydesigns.com/designing-with-the-magical-lightning-tokens-e087b6b838d1#.bv7d83t3w)

CODE:

```
.THIS .uiButtonBranded{
    background-color: token(colorBrand); 
    border-color:token(colorBrand); 
    color:token(colorTextButtonBrand);
```

---

But on the default Login pages, the Branding options are different.  And I cant seem to figure out the token names that will get my buttons to change with the branding editor.  As I mentioned before, it works great in the main site.

[image]

Any thoughts as to what these token values are?  Is there a reference Im missing?